# Question about python string

Tags: python, string

i have been asked to write a function which should be called in this way

```
foo("Hello")
```

This function also has to return values in this way:

```
[Hello( user = 'me', answer = 'no', condition = 'good'),
 Hello( user = 'you', answer = 'yes', condition = 'bad'),
]
```

the task has clearly asked to return string values. can anyone understand the purpose of this task in concepts of Python and help me on this?
would you please give me a code sample?

Comment: I honestly have no idea what the question is asking for. Can you please provide any additional information that you have?

Comment: I think, probably you need to crate a class called `Hello` override its `__str__` method and create another method which returns the list (array) of Object Hello with the desired attributes.....

Comment: Please do your own homework.  And please mark homework with the [homework] tag.  And please provide the code you started to write with **specific** questions on the problems you're **actually** having.  Please be aware this is not `do_my_homework_for_me.com`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Functions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions)

[Lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

[Classes](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html)

Create a class that has the desired attributes, then return a list of instances from the function.

Answer (score 0):

It could be something like this:

```
class Hello:
    def __init__(self, user, answer, condition):
        self.user = user
        self.answer = answer
        self.condition = condition

def foo():
    return [Hello( user = 'me', answer = 'no', condition = 'good'),
    Hello( user = 'you', answer = 'yes', condition = 'bad'),
    ]
```

Output of the `foo` function:

```
[<__main__.Hello instance at 0x7f13abd761b8>, <__main__.Hello instance at 0x7f13abd76200>]
```

Which is a list of class instances (objects).

You can use them this way:

```
for instance in foo():
    print instance.user
    print instance.answer
    print instance.condition
```

Which gives:

```
me
no
good
you
yes
bad
```